# Solr - index updates automatically

Tags: solr, solr4

In my data-config I handle data loading using:
query, deltaQuery,deltaImportQuery & deletedPkQuery.

I want to run updates automatically every X minutes.
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a cron job to execute the DeltaImportQuery via [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) at your specified interval.

Also consider using the DataImportScheduler that is described in the [Scheduling section of the DataImportHandler on the Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling).